# can't access ios bundle resource

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am adding my first .wav file to my iOS project using XCode 11.3.1.  I have tried various ways to access this resource:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "greetings.wav", withExtension: nil)
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "greetings", withExtension: "wav")
let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "greetings", ofType: "wav")
```

In all of these cases, fileURL is nil.  Other things I have tried:

- When I click on the .wav in Project Navigator, I see that Target Membership is checked for my target.
- I have ensured greetings.wav is in the same folder as my ViewController which is executing the above statement.
- I have also tried both the "Copy to Group" and "Copy to Folder Reference" when adding this resource

Nothing as of yet has produced a non-nil fileURL.  Any help/additional troubleshooting so that I can get a valid URL for my .wav file would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just offering possible suggestions here:

- Check if you have imported the AVFoundation Module
- Check if your resource is called "greetings.wav"

Comment: Thanks, but AVFoundation is already imported and resource is called greetings.wav in the File Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your file is available in Copy Bundle Resources under build settings

Comment: Yes, my file is visible under Copy Bundle Resources.  It indicates it is in a folder.  This folder also contains my viewController where the above code resides.  Should I still need to specify a subdirectory when building the url?